# I want to implement a Hide / View Section Items - functionality onPress Section Header

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

```
return (
    <View style={styles(theme).container}>
      <SectionList
        sections={listData.item}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
        renderItem={({item}) => renderItems(item)}
        renderSectionHeader={({section: {title, imageUrl}}) => (
          <CardWithImageAndTitle image={imageUrl} title={title} />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
          <View
            style={{
              borderBottomWidth: 0.8,
              borderColor: theme.text02,
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

I have a section list,
I want to implement a Hide / View Section Items - functionality `onPress` Section Header
please guide me
thank you